# Twitter media/upload image by its web url

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I followed the steps in [media/upload](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload). I wrote this function in python

`def upload_media(self,access_token,image_url):
    client = self.get_client(access_token)
    message = {'media' : image_url}
    encoded_status = urllib.urlencode(message)
    url =  "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?"+ encoded_status 
    resp, content = client.request(url,'post')
    return content`

And I got this :

`{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"media type unrecognized."}`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the error is in trying to upload a URL. The Twitter API requires you to upload a base64-encoded image.

See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload

So instead of the image's URL, it should be the file content:

```
with open('example.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
message = {'media':data}
```

Optionally (I still haven't figured out whether this is required or not, as different people give different answers), you could encode the image in base-64 encoding:

```
with open('example.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.encode('base64')
message = {'media':data}
```

Comment: My app is actually hosted on GAE and I just figure out that I can't write to file system   I need to edit my question thank you any way.